# Angular - How to change text-input status

Tags: angular

I am using Angular-7 for my web application. The detail view is shown below:

[image: text input]

```
 <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="responded">Quote Status</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="responded" name="responded" readonly [(ngModel)]="data.responded"/>
    </div>
 </div>
```

From the code above, when **data.responded** is 0 it should display **Inactive** and when it is 1, it should display **Active**.

How do I achieve this in text-input?

Comment: Use disabled attribute

Comment: Are you wanting to see the text "Inactive" / "Active" in place of "1" / "0" within the input? If so, perhaps a ternary? `[(ngModel)]="data.responded === 1 ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you would like the value of the Quote input field to change according to the value of data.responded. If so, you can bind to the value property of the input field using a ternary operator:

```
<div class="col-xs-4"> <div class="form-group"> <label for="responded">Quote Status</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="responded" name="responded" readonly [value]="!!data.responded ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'"/> </div> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Chellappan suggested in the comments, use the `disabled` attribute to do it.

Here, give this a try:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="responded">Quote Status</label>
    <input 
      type="text" 
      [disabled]="data.responded == 0" 
      class="form-control" 
      id="responded" 
      name="responded"
      [(ngModel)]="data.responded" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you don't want it disabled, you can also make the `readonly` attribute conditional:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="responded">Quote Status</label>
    <input 
      type="text" 
      [readonly]="data.responded == 0"
      class="form-control" 
      id="responded" 
      name="responded"
      [(ngModel)]="data.responded" />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e573n1-m6la6g?file=app/form-field-overview-example.ts) for your ref.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[value]` directive for this purpose combined with `ternary conditional operator`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="responded" name="responded"
               readonly [value]="data.responded === 0? 'Inactive': 'Active'"/>
```

> **[Working Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dpcubg)**